CatBoost crashes when launching Optuna
I want to tune a regressor catboost using Optuna and local GPU. The dataset is not very large: the training sample contains about 120k records and only 16 features (including categorical ones). I run the code:
RANDOM_SEED = 2906
n_trials = 100

def objective_cat(trial):
  params = {'iterations': trial.suggest_int('iterations', 100, 2000),
            'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 1e-5, 1e-1, log=True),
            'depth': trial.suggest_int('max_depth', 2, 16),
            'bagging_temperature': trial.suggest_uniform('bagging_temperature', 0, 1),
            'l2_leaf_reg': trial.suggest_float('l2_leaf_reg', 1e-5, 100, log=True),
            'random_seed': RANDOM_SEED,
            'loss_function': 'RMSE',
            'task_type': 'GPU'
            }

  cat_model = CatBoostRegressor(**params, cat_features=cat_features)
  cv = KFold(
      n_splits=10,
      shuffle=True,
      random_state=RANDOM_SEED
      )
  score = cross_val_score(
      cat_model, X_train, y_train, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1,
      scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error'
      )
  return -np.mean(score)

study_cat = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize',
                                 sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(
                                     seed=RANDOM_SEED,
                                     n_startup_trials=20,
                                     multivariate=True
                                     ),
                                 pruner=optuna.pruners.HyperbandPruner(
                                     min_resource=1,
                                     max_resource=100,
                                     reduction_factor=3
                                     ),
                                 study_name=f'optuna_cat')
optuna.logging.set_verbosity(optuna.logging.CRITICAL)
study_cat.optimize(
    objective_cat,
    n_trials=n_trials,
    n_jobs=-1,
    show_progress_bar=True
    )
best_params_cat = study_cat.best_params

And got an error:
TerminatedWorkerError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 39
     26 study_cat = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize',
     27                                  sampler=optuna.samplers.TPESampler(
     28                                      seed=RANDOM_SEED,
   (...)
     36                                      ),
     37                                  study_name=f'optuna_cat')
     38 optuna.logging.set_verbosity(optuna.logging.CRITICAL)
---> 39 study_cat.optimize(
     40     objective_cat,
     41     n_trials=n_trials,
     42     n_jobs=-1,
     43     show_progress_bar=True
...
    764     return self._result
    765 finally:

TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.

"Original" CatBoost (without Optuna and etc.) works fine with my GPU. How can I solve this problem?
Versions:
CatBoost 1.2.5
Optuna 4.0.0
My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
I tryed Optuna with CPU but there was no iterations for the whole hour!
Almost tried drop n_jobs=-1 and:
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'


I removed n_jobs=-1 from KFolds parameters and it works. But very slow :-(
